# Writing a piecewise polynomial function as a sum of truncated power functions

Tags: polynomials

Writing a piecewise polynomial function f(t) as a sum of truncated power functions p(t)= (t-c)^k

where f(t) is defined as 
$$
f(t) =
\begin{cases}
      0 &, 0 \leq t < 1 \\
      t - 1 &, 1 \leq t < 2 \\
      0 &, 2 \leq t < 3 \\
\end{cases}
$$

and p(t) is defined as
$$
p(t) =
\begin{cases}
      0 &, t < c \\
      (t - c)^k &, t \geq c \\
\end{cases}
$$

I don't exactly know a method on how to approach this apart from trail and error, which isn't proving to be very useful.

EDIT:

Solved. Forgot about the case of when (t-c)^0

f(t) = (1 - g(t))(h(t))

where g(t) has c = 2, k = 0 and h(t) has c = 1, k = 1, and both g(t) and h(t) are in the form of p(t)

s.t. (1 - g(t)) cancels out all h(t) when 2 <= t < 3, and h(t) is valid for 0 <= t < 2

Comment: $p$ is continuous, $f$ is not?

Comment: yes p is a continuous function, and f isn't

Answer (score 0):

Found the notes at http://azrael.digipen.edu/MAT300/notes/L6.pdf on page 3.
Using that I was able to derive the answer in the image below[image]

Comment: The notation is really unclear.

Comment: Replaced with an image, is that more helpful?